# How to set setContentView in another method?

Tags: java, android, xml, methods, setcontentview

I have an activity_main.xml with

```
tools:context="com.example.android.newwine.MainActivity"
```

and

```
<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="goToNext"/>
```

In my MainActivity.java file I have

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

and

```
public void gaNaarNext(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}
```

I have an activity_main2.xml file with

```
tools:context="com.example.android.newwine.MainActivity"
```

When I touch the button next now the activity_main2.xml will be used as ContentView, so that's correct, but when I do anything then (like touching a RadioButton or doing doesn't matter what) in my activity_main2.xml file what calls a method, it says: "New Wine is stopped." Whatever I do what calls a method, the app crashes. I tried much and if I'm going to paste everything I tried here this will be a long, long question:).

But has someone an answer? I really don't know what to do now, so I thought; let's ask something on Stackoverflow. Thanks already!

Comment: You're quite confusing me. What is the exception that you're getting? I'm assuming it's a Null Pointer Exception. Do not use the widgets that you had not instantiated.

Comment: Can you provide logcat please.

Answer (score 1):

You might prefer to use another activity or [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to change your UI as using the method `setContentView()` multiple times is not recomended because of all the drawing involved.

Since it seems like you don't want to switch activities fragments may be the easiest to use.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227950/android-is-using-setcontentview-multiple-times-bad-while-changing-layouts) addresses that matter as well.

Answer (score 0):

After you change your content view, the UI Elements on the screen have changed. All of the variables that you previously set up now point to the old screen - which no longer exists. Once you change your content view, you must set these variables to the correct elements on that layout file. Also, you may want to check out Fragments like Carlos Sifuentes said.

Answer (score 0):

> When I do anything then (like touching a `RadioButton` or doing doesn't matter what) in my `activity_main2.xml` file what calls a method, it says: "`New Wine is stopped.`" Whatever I do what calls a method, the `app crashes`.

The problem is you have used `activity_main2.xml` but you did'nt get the `reference` of `RadioButton` of `activity_main2.xml`. You should get all the view `reference` after setting new layout using `setContentView()` and then use as per your needs.

**Update your `gaNaarNext()` method as below:**

```
public void gaNaarNext(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    // For example: If your activity_main2 contains radio_button then do this
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_button);

    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            // Do something
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this will help~