# setText on ID not working in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a textview in my xml and I want to change the text from an intent. I've tried it before in the same class but on another xml and it works there. But after changing the contentView it don't work anymore. I want to set the displayName.

```js
package de.myapp.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UserAreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("");
        //setContentView(R.layout.nav_header_user_area);
        //final TextView displayName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayName);
        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        //String dpdisplayName = intent.getStringExtra("displayName");
        //displayName.setText(dpdisplayName);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        //if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //    return true;
        //}

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

XML:

```html
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Mr. Android"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:id="@+id/displayName" />
```

Comment: why do you have 2 layouts?

Comment: Because of the navigation. In the standard android navigation has the bar a own layout and the other layout is the main screen.

Comment: you can't have two setContentView in one activity.

Comment: And after setting the text in the first layout I want to go back to the main you understand?

Comment: Ah thats the point. What can I do?

Comment: Header and body part should be in one layout.

Comment: @ItsOdi1, im here again, but it seems that u cant use 2 layout or this is wrong. paste full code.

Comment: @W4R10CK I want to change the original title from a navigation activity "Android Studio" to the title from my intent

Comment: Have a look at this as setContentView() is set twice
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227950/android-is-using-setcontentview-multiple-times-bad-while-changing-layouts

Comment: Find more info in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227950/android-is-using-setcontentview-multiple-times-bad-while-changing-layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED] Use like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setTitle("");
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);

 Intent intentMain = getIntent();
 String dpdisplayName = intentMain.getStringExtra("displayName");

 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
 drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
 toggle.syncState();

 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
 TextView navdisplayName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.displayName);
 navdisplayName.setText(dpdisplayName);
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Because the displayName isn't in the activity_user_are but in the nav_header_user_area. Thats the problem and the app crashs

Comment: yes, I missed that change contentView to `nav_header_user_area `

Comment: but after setting the displayName I need to go back to the activity_user_area because the rest of the code plays here.

Comment: going back means, is it an activity or what ?

Comment: Yes, its a navigation activity

Comment: start activity to that activity. or backpress.

Comment: I don't understand. Thats so difficult

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133083/discussion-between-w4r10ck-and-itsodi1).

Answer (score 1):

*At First Remove*

**Calling Multiple time**

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area); // Remove from 2nd time
```

**Final View**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Dont call setTitle(""); Here
    setContentView(R.layout.nav_header_user_area);
    final TextView displayName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayName);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String dpdisplayName = intent.getStringExtra("displayName");
    displayName.setText(dpdisplayName);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("");
  //code goes on here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

while setting setContentView() second time, you have eventually changes your attached view hierarchy tree. Your changes to textview will no longer be visible since its not even attached to the activity