# How to set the result text in EditText from "zXingScannerView" with result.getText()?

Tags: android, zxing, zxing.net

I've been working with zXingScannerView and I went to set the result text in my Edittext in the same Activity but it does not work!!
Note:it shows in a Toast:

```
Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(),"Code Scaned ! :"+result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

My Code :

```
public void scan(View view){
    zXingScannerView =new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(zXingScannerView);
    zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    zXingScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_);
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_);
    Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(),"Code Scaned ! :"+result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Scan_Activity.this.scan.setText(result.getText());
    zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you only need to call setContentView() once in onCreate(), the issue is occurring because you are calling setContentView() again in handleResult().

```
 @Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(),"Code Scaned ! :"+result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Scan_Activity.this.scan.setText(result.getText());
    zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

}
```

Also there is not need of calling setContentView() again in onPause() because your layout is already get created when onCreate() is called.

This will work for sure. Also check [this for more reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227950/android-is-using-setcontentview-multiple-times-bad-while-changing-layouts)

Comment: i use setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_); to get back to the scan activity !

Comment: Just for clarification setContentView() only changes the layout of the activity , you have to call onBackPressed() to go back to scan activity.

Comment: so ,i hav my dashboard activity i i go to scan activity with using: public void click_bt1(View v){
        Intent i=new Intent(this,Scan_Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

Comment: the scan activity :||public class Scan_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    private EditText scan,titel;
    private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;