# Taking an edittext field and displaying in a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview, illegalstateexception

I am relatively new to coding but have some experience in Java and Android. I have a really basic problem that I have done over and over again but for some reason, this occurrence doesn't work!

I have an `edittext` field which is populated by the user. When an enter button is pressed the app then takes this and saves it as a String. The String is then used to populate the `TextView` with the user input.

I have created the `findviewbyids`, I have set the String to equal the `edittext` input and then set the text in the text view to be the String as per the code below. I have checked previous apps I have made and this has always worked before...

```
package com.example.android.golfhandicap;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText playerName;
TextView playerOneName;
String name;
int handicap;
EditText playerHandicap;
TextView playerOneHcp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.front_page);

}
//set view by IDs
public void views() {
    playerName = findViewById(R.id.inputPlayerName);
    playerOneName = findViewById(R.id.playerOneName);
    playerHandicap = findViewById(R.id.inputPlayerHcp);
    playerOneHcp = findViewById(R.id.playerOneHcp);

}

/**
 * Add the codes for the button to navigate around the app
 */


public void enterScore1(View view) {
setContentView(R.layout.front_page);
}

public void addPlayer(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.new_player);
}

public void addScore(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.input_page);
}


public void enterPlayer(View view) {

    views();


    name = playerName.getText().toString();
//handicap = Integer.parseInt(playerHandicap.getText().toString());



playerOneName.setText(name);
//playerOneHcp.setText(handicap);



    Toast.makeText(this, "player name is " + name + " and handicap is 
" + handicap , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.front_page);



}
}
```

The XML for the page with the text view I want to display the `String` in:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="visible"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appName2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Golf handicap"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:editable="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/playerOneName"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:editable="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appName2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/playerOneName2"
    android:editable="false"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playerOneName3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/playerOneName3"
    android:editable="false"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playerOneName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addScore"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:onClick="addScore"
    android:text="Add new score"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/addPlayer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addPlayer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:onClick="addPlayer"
    android:text="Add new player"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addScore"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/playerOneHcp"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:editable="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/playerOneName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appName2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:editable="false"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/playerOneName2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:editable="false"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/playerOneName3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playerOneHcp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The XML for the layout with the `edittext` which I get the user input from:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/enterHcpText"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:editable="false"
    android:text="Current handicap :"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enterAgeText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/enterAgeText"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:editable="false"
    android:text="Player age :"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enterNameText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/enterNameText"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:editable="false"
    android:text="Player name :"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appName3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appName3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:editable="false"
    android:text="Golf handicap"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputPlayerName"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
    android:maxLength="25"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appName3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputPlayerAge"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputPlayerName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputPlayerHcp"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputPlayerAge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/enterPlayer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="148dp"
    android:onClick="enterPlayer"
    android:text="Enter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputPlayerHcp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If I comment out the line `p1Name.setText(name);` then it works fine, I have a toast to check the name is taken and name is set as the input. So there seems to be something wrong with the `p1Name`. I have checked and triple checked all the IDs are correct.

I have spent over an hour now trying to figure it out and can't see what I am doing wrong!

This is the lines I get on logcat (These are all the lines shown in red)

```
2019-01-24 23:29:39.376 9545-9545/com.example.android.golfhandicap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.golfhandicap, PID: 9545
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.android.golfhandicap.MainActivity.enterPlayer(MainActivity.java:65)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: any error in logcat? please post the xml tag for id `playerOneName`

Comment: I seem to get 2 errors looking at Logcat (Never used it before so not sure if these are helpful,

Comment: The first error is InvocationTargetException the second is a nullpointerexception.

Comment: This is the xml for the textview of playerOneName      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerOneName"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appName2" />

Comment: I am still new to android studio, I have just started a java module as part of my degree. My logcat contains massive amounts of info, the 2 errors above are what I believe the problem is. But I have not yet done any studying of the logcat errors.

Comment: Please edit your original post and paste all your relevante code there. That would be: MainActivity and XML for Main Activity (or the relevant activity files). It is hard to know the problem without the full code

Comment: Thanks I have edited the original question. Some of the xml files aren't fully finished but these are text and edittext views I am not yet trying to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply because of the following:

1. you haven't bind the view with the `findViewById`. This is because of the following code:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.front_page);

       // Here you haven't bind the view.
   }
   ```

you should directly bind the view with your `views()` method. So, change the code to this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.front_page);

        // bind the view.
        views();
    }
```

2. You're changing the layout view each time a button is clicked with this method:

   ```
   public void addScore(View view) {
       setContentView(R.layout.input_page);
   }
   ```

which is become one of the source for your problem. First, it's not recommended because you're [redrawing entire layout when calling setContentView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227950/android-is-using-setcontentview-multiple-times-bad-while-changing-layouts). Second, you need to make sure all the layout `onClick` is implemented in your code.

3. Last but not the least, you better using `setOnClickListener` in code instead `onClick` attribute in layout. It is because you should separate between logic and UI.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I have changed the findviewbtids into the onCreate method but it didn't help a great deal. Some of the other things you mentioned I am not familiar with. I have used onClickListener in another app but it was mainly copied from a solution online. I need to read up on how to do it properly

Comment: Long story short, you just need to set the layout and bind the view on the layout to the code before the button `onClick` can works. You have the problem only because you haven't familiarize yourself with how Android code works. Just take your time to learn a bit deeper ;)